# Clock cycle in pipelining and single-clock cycle implementation

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

There are two mechanisms to execute instructions.

1. Single clock cycle implementation
2. pipelining.

In MIPS architecture(from the book *Computer organization and design*), instruction has 5 stages.

So, in single clock cycle implementation, which means during one clock cycle, 5 stages are executed for one instruction.

For example, load instruction(it has 5 stages) is executed in one clock cycle. So other instructions can be executed after this one clock cycle.
Let's assume that one clock cycle is 10 secs.

And now, in pipelining, multiple instructions can be overlapped. I'm confused from this concept comparing to one clock cycle's time in above example.

[image]

In here to Execute 5 instructions, it needs 9 clock cycles. It means to execute 5 instructions, it needs 90 secs. But in single clock cycle implementation, it just needs 50 secs to execute 5 instructions. Pipelining needs more clock cycles.(Not good) Am I thinking wrong?? or Am I missing something??

And here, So, to execute first instruction `lw $10, 20($1)`, it needs 50 secs??

Comment: *Let's assume that one clock cycle is 10 secs.*  1 nanosecond would be a more likely choice (1GHz CPU).  Even a very early RISC that might use a pipeline that simple would probably run at 100MHz.  So you're off by 9 or 10 orders of magnitude in your guess at what might be a good/reasonable example...

Comment: What you're missing is that pipelining allows you to clock the design faster than if a whole instruction has to fetch/decode/execute/writeback in a single cycle.  (More typically, a non-pipelined CPU like Intel's original 8086 would take multiple cycles for each instruction, instead of running the clock really slow and subdividing it to time internal operations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the major misconception you are having is that you consider a duration of a clock cycle in both designs to be the same, which is not.
Lets denote a clock cycle in single cycle design as `X` and a clock cycle in pipeline design as `Y`.
In a single cycle design 5 instructions will take `5X` cycles and in a pipeline design this will take `9Y` cycles.

Now we need to find a relationship between `X` and `Y`.
Now think of a case where you have only single instruction to execute.
In a single cycle design this will take `X` cycles and in a pipeline design this will take `5Y`. If both are clocked at the same rate, `X` should be equal to `5Y`.

Now lets do a bit of substitution maths :-)

Single cycle - `5X`

Pipeline     - `9Y`

Substituting  `X` = `5Y`

Single cycle - `25Y`

Pipeline     - `9Y`

There you go. Single cycle design is 2.7X slower than a multi cycle design.

Comment: Waiting for 5 instructions to go all the way from start to finish of the pipelined design is a bit unrealistic.  The steady-state situation of executing a long stream of instructions is ideally `5Y` cycles.  (Of course, stalls due to limited parallelism and branch mispredictions will slow things down, so 9Y might be realistic after all).

Comment: But the way you're using it, it would be more reasonable to expect the pipelined CPU's time for 1 instruction to go all the way through the pipeline to be about equal to the non-pipelined CPU's time for one instruction (if you pipeline the minimum amount necessary).  So the clock speed ratio could easily be as large as 5:1 (vs. a silly design that's clocked so slow it can run every instruction in a single cycle).